# Why does reference optimization prevents from registering DLLs?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, regsvr32

I am registering a DLL in a Visual Studio post build event, and `regsrv32` is failing as if a library dependency was missing. The DLL has a DllRegisterServer entry point, a `DEF` file and was correctly setup. the registration was done correctly until we changed library dependencies. Right .

Now that the DLL depends on a ***cross compiled library***, I have to disable the reference [optimization option /OPT:REF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to make the registration successful again. Why is that?

Furthermore `dependency walker` was not able to find entry points of dependent libraries (ffmpeg libs). See the difference `/OPT:NOREF` vs `/OPT:REF` below:

[image: No reference optimization vs reference optimization]

Note that the linking process is successful.

Comment: Regsvr32 can only work if the DLL exports the DllRegisterServer entrypoint.  None is visible so that's going to fail.  But you didn't get there yet, something seriously wrong about how you build this, whatever it may be.  Forgetting to tell the linker about a DEF file would be a lead.  If it doesn't know that a function needs to be exported then /OPT:REF is likely to eliminate it.

Comment: @HansPassant the dll I am registering has a DEF file, and a DllRegisterServer entry point. But it depends on libraries which don't have def files (they are cross-compiled).